# Rename project with AppCode

Tags: xcode, appcode

I have an existing project in AppCode that I would like to use as a starting point for a new project. So I want to make a copy of the project and then rename this copy. Is there any way to do this using AppCode, or do I have to copy the project directory and then manually rename all instances of the project name across all the files and directories in the project?

If I right click on the project main folder, then click refactor, and then select rename, the IDE shows a error dialog indicating that you cannot rename the project main. I suppose this is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find no way to reliably rename a project in AppCode. I ended up renaming the project directory and running this in the terminal:

```
find . -type f -name '*' -exec sed -i '' s/oldname/newname/ {} +
```

An alternative would also have been to open the project in XCode and rename it there and then open it again with AppCode.

Comment: Really awkward! Did you file an enhancement request with JetBrains?

Comment: Did not work for me, but also destroyed my .git stuff, be careful if you have not pushed...